# Enable wagtail DateField when a wagtail BooleanField is true

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I need to have a wagtail DateField disabled by default, but if the content author checks a box (a wagtail BooleanField) then the field should be enabled and required. I'm struggling to find the best way to solve this, I haven't found documentation on how to do this. I was thinking about using Django signals or wagtail hooks but it does seem like a complex solution for what I think should be a common use case. So I was wondering if anyone has a better alternative or point me to the right direction.

Comment: You should not disable this in the model (in fact you could just make the `DateField` nullable, and drop the `BooleanField`, but you need to implement this in the layer (both in JavaScript and at the form implementation).

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe this is possible currently in Wagtail (as of Wagtail 2.2). Not natively, at least.

What you can do, however, is add custom JavaScript to your admin with a snippet like this:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles import static
from django.utils.html import format_html

from wagtail.core import hooks


@hooks.register("insert_global_admin_js", order=100)
def global_admin_js():
    """Add custom.js to Wagtail Admin."""
    return format_html('<script src="{}"></script>', static("js/custom.js"))
```

And then inside your `custom.js` file, you can add a JavaScript event to detect when the boolean field is checked or not, and then find and select the DateField and disable or hide it.

As Willem Van Onsem has mentioned, you'll want to make the `DateField` nullable and blank so you can save the Page (as a form) when the `DateField` is empty.